# getResourceAsStream fails under new environment?

Tags: java, resources, classloader

Hallo,

i have following line of code:

```
InputStream passoloExportFileInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml");
```

and i know that jar with com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml is in classpath.

It worked under "previous environment", which is maven2 build.

Now, i evaluate maven3 and it doesn't work! I know, that if i change the code to be:

```
InputStream passoloExportFileInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml");
```

it works great (i just removed the first slash from the resource path).

Btw, i use Linux. First slash in path normally means "from the root directory", so if this logic is sound for java resource loading as well, first example should never have worked!?

Questions:  is something wrong with the first code sample, i.e. with **/com/** and not **com/**? Is it just bad code or it means something different?

thank you!

Comment: Devons's answer works for me. Also, i found in
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html that:
"
The methods in ClassLoader use the given String as the name of the resource without applying any absolute/relative transformation (see the methods in Class). The name should not have a leading "/".
"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you are getting the resource. When you use a `ClassLoader` as in:

```
InputStream stream= getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml");
```

The leading '/' is meaningless. So, the correct form is "com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml".

If, instead you use a 'Class', as in:

```
InputStream stream= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/thinkplexx/lang/de/general.xml");
```

You get a different behavior. The `Class.getResourceAsStream` will consider classes without a leading '.' to be relative to the package containing the class. Resources specified with a leading '.' are absolute, or resolved relative to the root of the jar.

So, if `this` is a reference to `com.example.SomeThing`, then the expected behavior is:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c.xml")  ==> a/b/c.xml
getClass().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c.xml")  ==> com/example/a/b/c.xml
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c.xml")  ==> a/b/c.xml
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c.xml")  ==> Incorrect
```

Maven2 was being lax and allowing the last form.