# How do I get GrailsRootLoader to resolve resources with absolute paths?

Tags: grails, groovy

In my grails app, I use a third party library which makes heavy use of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/some/thing")` - resource loading with absolute paths.

Resources are in `grails-app/conf`. Using `grails run-app` the classloader used is a `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader`. With this classloader, resolving fails when absolute paths are used. Resources **do** resolve without the preceeding "/" - e.g. `some/thing` does resolve. Resources also do resolve **with** the preceeding "/" in unit tests or when the app is packaged as a war. This both does not really help.

How do I get `GrailsRootLoader` to resolve absolute paths when I run the app with the `grails` command ?

PS: I use grails-2.0.3 on Linux and tried Java versions 1.7.0_01 (Oracle) and 1.6.0_24 (OpenJDK).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getResourceAsStream fails under new environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238562/getresourceasstream-fails-under-new-environment)

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried it, but it looks like this should be fixed in the third party lib : [getResourceAsStream fails under new environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238562/getresourceasstream-fails-under-new-environment)